How to change language (Lithuanian) on iPad with magic keyboard?
I have an iPad 11 Air 2024. And I also have magic keyboard. The problem is I cannot write letters such as ą or č or ū and so more.
I can only press on my iPad that shows a letter, hold it for 2s and then select normal Lithuanian letter, but when i write with a keyboard it would be amazing to have for example 1 as ą (Lithuanian), 2 as č (Lithuanian) like other normal keyboards have.

Welcome to Ask Different.  What version of iPadOS are you running? It might not make much difference but it’s a good detail

Go to settings / general / keyboard / hardware keyboard and tap on Lithuanian and make sure the Lithuanian mapping on the list that appears is checked.
https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-250006655
